# Firth's Penalised Logistic Regression - high chi-squared values

Tags: r, logistic-regression, chi-squared

I am analysing a household budget survey dataset with the aim of analysing whether households who spend more on alcohol also spend more on other discretionary items such as restaurants and entertainment (large sample size over 200,000).

Given the large number of households reporting zero expenditure for each of these items, I had non-normally distributed errors in my linear regression model and therefore used a logistic regression. 
When I ran my logistic regression I came across quasi-complete separation. Based on an analysis of the literature, it seems a Firth’s penalised logistic regression was the most appropriate:

```
Regression <- logistf(restaurant_spender ~ alc_spender + income_quintiles + eduation_hh, data = alcohol, weights = weight, firth=FALSE)
```

Where:

- restaurant_spender is binary (=1 if they spend anything on restaurants and 0 otherwise)
- alc_spender same as above but for alcohol
- income_quintiles is a categorical variable separating households into one of five income quintiles
- education_hh is a categorical variable indicating the highest level of education for the household head.

And to get the odds ratios:

```
exp(coef(Regression))
```

This produces odds ratio I would expect and my confidence intervals make sense. However, my Chi-squared values are all infinite.

I have tabbed all of my independent variables against my dependent variable and there are no categories with 0 (in fact, they are evenly distributed). 
My questions are:

1) Am I doing anything obviously wrong in running a Firth’s penalised logistic regression in R?

2) Are infinite chi-squared values implausible?

3) Is there some other way in R to test why I am getting quasi-separation apart from tabbing independent and dependent variables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the reason for setting firth=FALSE ? You are running a normal logistic regression with this

Comment: That was a mistake. I ran it with TRUE and am getting similar results. Thanks.